# Зачем для application/x-www-form-urlencoded заменять "%20" на "+"?

Tags: javascript

> Для application/x-www-form-urlencoded пробелы должны быть заменены на "+", поэтому вам может понадобиться encodeURIComponent с дополнительной заменой "%20" на "+".

Источник: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Потому что «...-urlencoded», то есть «закодировано как в URL».

Comment: @Arhad В URL “%20” - допустимо, а в application/x-www-form-urlencoded - нет. Я и спрашиваю почему не допустимо. Это разные вещи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Идем на [wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_MIME-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2#x). Для типа данных `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` указана ссылка на документ [HTML 4.01 Specification, Section 17.13.4.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1) в котором написано следующее:

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> This is the default content type. Forms submitted with this content type must be encoded as follows:
>
> 1. Control names and values are escaped. **Space characters are replaced by '+'**, and then reserved characters are escaped as described in [RFC1738], section 2.2: Non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by '%HH', a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. Line breaks are represented as "CR LF" pairs (i.e., '%0D%0A').
> 2. The control names/values are listed in the order they appear in the document. The name is separated from the value by '=' and name/value pairs are separated from each other by `&'.

Comment: А есть какое-то объяснение, почему space characters are replaced именно by '+'? Или «исторически сложилось»™?

Comment: Доп. вопрос: `encodeURIComponent(search).replace(/%20/g, "+");` - безопасно использовать? Разве "%20" не может совпасть с кодирующей последовательностью которая кодирует какой то другой символ?

Comment: Возможно объяснение есть именно такого решения для спецификации, но я его не знаю. `%20` ни с чем совпасть не может кроме пробела. Ни в однобайтовых кодировках, ни в многобайтовых. В той же UTF-8, в символах представленных несколькими байтами не должно встречаться байтов со значением от `00` до `7F`.

Comment: @Visman а если [En Quad](https://unicode-table.com/ru/2000/) в UTF-16BE? :)

Comment: @andreymal, а UTF-16 и UTF-32 пользуются в вэбе?

Answer (score 1):

Для MIME `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` используется такая же схема кодирования, как и для URL (ибо «...-urlencoded», то есть «закодировано как в URL»).

В свою очередь, в URL кодирование пробела плюсом является договорённостью. Причина этой договорённости банальна — читаемость. Дело в том, что web создавался в англоязычных США, и об использовании нелатинских адресов тогда даже не задумывались (или задумывались, но решили, что таких будет крайне немного), а потому каждая буква кодировалась как есть, без escape-последовательностей.

Сравните какой-нибудь:

> www.example.org/fileName.asp?param1=some+Param+with+Long+length&bar=5000

и:

> www.example.org/fileName.asp?param1=some%20Param%20with%20Long%20length&bar=5000

Думаю, не только мне прочитать первый вариант проще и быстрее, особенно в случае слов, начинающихся с больших букв.

***P. S:*** В случае использования нелатинских символов, когда вся строка состоит из одних escape-последовательностей, разницы в способах записи пробела никакой, да.